# Steps to enable and use iconv on Windows with Indy 10.5.9

Tags: delphi, cross-platform, indy, iconv

For cross-platform development with Internet Direct (Indy), it can be useful to enable [iconv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) support instead of the OS-specific Windows character conversions.

This would allow to continue developing and testing code on Windows in the Delphi IDE, but still be able to find conversion related issues before compiling the code on a different platform.

**Indy 10 already includes code to use the iconv API on Linux and Windows.**

On Windows, some preparation is required:

- copy the iconv API DLL to the app folder or the search path
- define the **use_iconv** conditional symbol

The intention of this question is to help getting started with iconv on the Windows platform.

Comment: Neither Wikipedia nor Google guide me to a suitably authoritative website to download a Windows iconv.dll from, where did you get yours?

Comment: @StijnSanders a software collection which includes iconv is the GnuWin project at gnuwin32.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0):

If I have a quick look at the iconv.h I found with the [gettext for windows sourceforge project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gettext/), and if I understood the C code correctly, a wrapper-unit for iconv.dll could look like this, and could be used on the input and output of Indy components.

```
unit iconv;

interface

//based on version 1.9.1 https://sourceforge.net/projects/gettext/

type
  TIconv = pointer;

function iconv_open(const PAnsiChar:tocode; const PAnsiChar:fromcode): TIconv; cdecl;
function iconv(cd:TIconv; var inbuf:PAnsiChar; var inbytesleft:integer; var output:PAnsiChar; var outbytesleft:integer): integer; cdecl;
function iconv_close(cd:TIconv): integer; cdecl;

const
  ICONV_TRIVIALP            =0;  // int *argument
  ICONV_GET_TRANSLITERATE   =1;  // int *argument
  ICONV_SET_TRANSLITERATE   =2;  // const int *argument
  ICONV_GET_DISCARD_ILSEQ   =3;  // int *argument
  ICONV_SET_DISCARD_ILSEQ   =4;  // const int *argument

type
  TiconvlistDoOne=function(namescount:cardinal; const names:PAnsiChar; data:pointer): integer; cdecl;

function iconvctl(cd:TIconv; request:integer; argument:pointer): integer; cdecl;
procedure iconvlist(do_one:TiconvlistDoOne; data:pointer); cdecl;
procedure libiconv_set_relocation_prefix(const orig_prefix:PAnsiChar; const curr_prefix:PAnsiChar); cdecl;

implementation

function iconv_open; external 'iconv.dll';
function iconv; external 'iconv.dll';
function iconv_close; external 'iconv.dll';
function iconvctl; external 'iconv.dll';
procedure iconvlist; external 'iconv.dll';
procedure libiconv_set_relocation_prefix; external 'iconv.dll';

end.
```

Comment: Indy already has the code to access the iconv API. I will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

Free Pascal has an iconv header (package iconvenc), and that either is delphi compatible or should be easily updatable. Get it from [FPC websvn interface module iconvenc](http://svn.freepascal.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/packages/iconvenc/) or the latest RC (2.6.2rc1), since it might have updated since the year old 2.6.0.

But it is more complicated than just providing the header, since iconv on windows doesn't support errno, and thus can't handle EILSEQ and EI2BIG, so you need to properly allocate memory up front (like 4*charsize).

I got code how to handle non errno iconv targets [PHP](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/iconv/iconv.c?revision=280602&view=markup), but it hasn't been tested very well. (see src/iconvert.inc)

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! I updated my question, Indy already has the code to use a iconv DLL on the Windows platform. My question only asks for basic documentation on this feature.

Comment: Then, make sure that the DLL that you found is equal to the one intended by Indy. See if they don't have a copy on the FTP server somewhere. Different builds on Windows might have different tradeoffs wrt the errno issue.

Comment: Indy does not provide its own copy of the ICONV library for any platform. It uses whatever DLL is installed on a platform or provided by the user. The current ICONV support code in Indy does not use `errno` at all since it cannot access `errno` in a platform-independant manner. However, I have done some work (that is not checked in yet) to add `errno` support to the `IdIconv.pas` unit under Windows (via msvcrt.dll) and Unix (via `cerrno`), but it is still experimental at best.

Comment: If the PHP iconv really updates that errno, and if it is accessable in a threadsafe (from Delphi in a version independent way). I don't think PHP (see link) has the option to disable checking errno for nothing.